# BlackBerry WebWorks: Create new Contacts Group

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

We're investigating if it's possible to create a new Contacts Group with the BlackBerry 10 WebWerks HTML5 API.
We have found the [API Description](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/beta/blackberry.pim.contacts.html)  for the Contacts API, but couldn't find any Information if it's possible to create and/or use a contacts group for it. 
Any clue/experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got an answer from Blackberry itself, which said that it's not possible at the moment. If required, you can build your own cordova plugin by extending the original plugin at https://github.com/blackberry/cordova-blackberry-plugins/tree/master/plugin/com.blackberry.pim.contacts

They even provide a template for custom plugins at https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/tree/master/BB10-Cordova/Template